# Synchronizing multiple audio sources over a network

Tags: networking, audio, synchronization, rtp, ntp

**The problem in short form is the following:**

*I'm buffering (real-time analysis) multiple audio sources from different locations and I want to sync them with millisecond precision when I've retrieved them in my server.*

**What I've discovered so far:**

The reason I'm doing this is to analyze sound that microphones are enclosing. For this to work NTP is implemented so that should be sufficient clock-synchronizing-wise.
Right now I'm able to access a RTP stream but is it possible to access a time-stamp in that stream? How should I buffer?

Other ideas are welcome if they are better ofcourse ;)

Comment: I think this is the wrong forum, superuser or serverfault will be more efficient.

Comment: You're streaming multiple audio sources over the network to one box? And this box needs to synchronize them [but only to millisecond precision] for correlation / analysis? Since it sounds like the machines are on a reliable network (given that they're in the same NTP domain), you could choose to skip RTP and roll-your-own streaming protocol over TCP (if possible jitter doesn't bother you, since the data would have synchronization timestamps/sample numbers embedded) or UDP (easiest-- include a sample start number in the header of each datagram and not care about the 1/10000 packets dropped).

Comment: @MatthewHall that's what we're implementing. We found out some way to get the timestamps but it was on a higher level and it would seem that we need to extract raw data and check the timestamps which are embedded directly instead. Please post this as an answer and I will accept it!